# Magic with Memory

Tags: memory, compiler-construction

How does the compiler know that it is going to take the value from "4 byte" memory address of `a`variable.
Let's say:

```
int a =9;
float b=3.7;
double d=345.987;
```

How does compiler know that a is 4 bytes when it takes out the value when needed.For double , how does it come to know that it has to take data from say 0x100 to 0x107 (8 bytes) and not from say 0x100 to 0x109 (10 bytes).Is there some extra information stored .If yes,what extra memory does it take?

Comment: It looks up in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table

Answer (score 0):

There is no extra information needed, the lengths of data types are fixed and defined.

You can read more about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).